# Calculating the probability of specific number drawn in lotto after 5 previous numbers were drawn

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

Good day, busy with the following problem. If you guys can please be so kind to direct me in the right direction. My solution doesn't seem right to me.

Question:

In a game of Lotto, balls are numbered 1 through to 44. They are all placed in a barrel and six balls are drawn without replacement. The balls are of the same size and are equally likely to be drawn. The first five balls drawn out are numbered 34, 2, 15, 29 and 42. What is the probability that the next ball drawn out will be number 26?

My first solution was:

> After 5 balls were drawn that means only 39 balls left in the pot so the odds of picking 26 is 1 in 39 which results in 1/39 and a 2.5% chance.

But given that this is a statistics assignment I figured I most likely should do it using probability methods etc.

So my second solution was:

> Event A: Ball 26 is drawn
>
> Event B: Balls 34, 2, 15, 29 and 42 are drawn
>
> P(A|B) = P(A and B) / P(B)
>
> P(A|B) = (1/44) * (5/44) / (5/44)
>
> P(A|B) = (5/1936) / (5/44)
>
> P(A|B) = (5/1936) * (44/5)
>
> P(A|B) = 220/9815
>
> P(A|B) = 44/1963
>
> P(A|B) = 0.022
>
> 2.2% chance of ball number 26 being drawn next.

Please assist :)

Comment: Your first argument is right.  Your calculations in the second are all wrong.  The probability of picking $5$ specific balls is not $\frac5{44}$, to begin with.

Comment: The first expression in your second solution is (1/44 * 5/44)/(5/44), which is simply 1/44, the chance that you draw a specific ball among the original 44. The chance that you draw 5 specific balls isn't 5/44, anyhow. No need to overcomplicate, go with the first solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of choosing $k$ specific cards from $44$ is $\frac1{\binom{44}{k}}$ since there are $\binom{44}{k}$ equally likely ways to choose $k$ cards.  This gives a denominator of $1/\binom{44}5$.  There are $\binom{44}6$ ways to choose $6$ specific cards, so the probability of drawing all $6$ is $$\frac1{\binom{44}{6}}$$
However, we are requiring that a specific card come last among the $6$, so the probability that we first draw $5$ specified cards and then a specific sixth card is  $$\frac16\frac1{\binom{44}{6}}$$
Therefore,   $$\Pr(A|B)=\frac16\frac{\binom{44}5}{\binom{44}6}=\frac1{39}$$

---

Another, perhaps clearer way to calculate $\Pr(A\cup B)$ is to use permuatations instead of combinations.  There are $5!$ admissible draws, since we can choose the first five cards in any order, but the sixth is fixed.  There are 
$$44\cdot43\cdot42\cdot41\cdot40\cdot39$$ so the proabability is $$\frac{5!}{44\cdot43\cdot42\cdot41\cdot40\cdot39}$$ which you can check is the same as before.

Comment: I didn't say the numerator is $1/\binom{44}{6}$.  I said it is one-sixth of that.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Maybe I stated it sloppily, but the probability that we choose five specified cards followed by a sixth specified card is clearly $\frac16$ of the probability that we draw $6$ specified cards, don't you agree?  If so, what are you getting so worked up about?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Just downvote it.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe I beg your pardon.  I lost my temper.  If I  said "this draw is acceptable only one-sixth of the time," would that meet your objection?  That's what I had in mind.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe No, I mean with probability $\frac{1}{\binom{44}{6}}$ we draw the $6$ specified cards, but only $\frac16$ of the time does the required card come last.  I'm calculating probabilities, not numbers of hands.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe I'll try to make it more explicit.  Sorry I was impatient earlier, but I couldn't understand what you were saying, and I got frustrated.  Probably getting cabin fever.

Comment: no problem. I always learn a ton reading your answers. I apologize for not being more clear with what I was saying. You are an amazing asset to stackexchange.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Wow.  Thank you.  I think I'm blushing.